# DIALux alternative for linux?

Tags: software-recommendation, alternative

I'm wondering if an alternative for DIALux lighting simulation software exists? It's really important for me as I replaced Autocad with Draftsight I still need DIALux without running it with Virtualbox to fully move to Ubuntu (finally!). Tried Wine, but it's not working. Google also doesn't know any software for my needs. Any electrical enineers on Ubuntu that can help me out?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't user GUI friend but true UNIX-way:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiance_%28software%29
- http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6479

Comment: Wikipedia is just background information (not a list of software) and the article was 10 year old at the time of writing, which is already 10 years ago. Low-quality answer that proves that they didn't read the tour